# ExpandableListView duplicating checkbox check

Tags: android

hi I am using ExpandableListview in android. My requirement is, at a time one group plus its child group must selected(using check boxes). If I go for another group then the previously selected group should get unchecked.

But From my code when I check first group automatically the last group will check. This is my issue and below is my code. Thanks in advance.

listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                CheckBox last = holder.groupCHeck;
                CheckBox current = (CheckBox) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.groupCheckBox);
                last.setChecked(false);
                current.setChecked(true);
                if (listExpandedPosition.size() >= 1) {
                    if (listExpandedPosition.get(0) != groupPosition) {
                        listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(listExpandedPosition
                                .get(0));
                        last.setChecked(false);
                    }
                } else {
                }
                if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                } else {
                    listView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                }
                if (!listExpandedPosition.isEmpty())
                    listExpandedPosition.clear();
                listExpandedPosition.add(groupPosition);
                holder.groupCHeck = current;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that usually happens with listview,expandable listview and gridview.These widgets doesn't maintain states of checked checkbox.
Have a look at this example,you will get the idea how to deal with that...
http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a SparseBooleanArray or Arraylist and hold Checked and Unchecked states in the array itself and set it accordingly, Or if you are using a custom Java Pojo/Object add another field for getting setting a boolean for checked/unchecked state. This is a common scenario because AdapterView recycle views and items for saving memory.